# Failed with python asyncio

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

This is pretty silly error, but I fail to solve it.
P.S. apparently, I'm don't know some basic asyncio features:)

```
async def some_func():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def main(*tasks):
    await asyncio.gather(tasks)

def do_opt():
    if True:
        asyncio.run(main(asyncio.create_task(some_func())))

do_opt() # RuntimeError: no running event loop
```

Comment: It works fine for me, doesn't raise error.

Comment: How you are run it, `do_opt()` ?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to call `do_opt`?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: TLDR: Do not wrap some_func in a task explicitly.